# textures get flipped across y-axis on a material but not on Actor

Tags: java, libgdx, textures

Textures seem to be flipped vertically when applied to a material. The image shows what I mean. I also applied the same textures to an Actor, but when used with actors no flipping is seen.

I get the textures from texture atlas. This is the relevant code:

```
   private TextureAtlas textAtlas;

//show method
   textAtlas = Assets.assetManager.get("atlases/textAtlas.pack");


// assigning textures to material
   materials.get(i).set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(textAtlas.findRegion("nameOfTexture"+i)));
```

[image]

Looks like I have missed some option that needs to be checked to flip the textures. Or is this a problem with the models I use? What workaround do you propose?

Answer (score 2):

you can try to use `public void flip(boolean x, boolean y)` take a look [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#flip-boolean-boolean-)

Comment: Thank you. That is a workaround and if nothing else comes around it will do the job. The problem is that I also use these same textures on some actors.  So flipping them for a material will also be seen when used with Actors.

Comment: It flips the TextureRegion, not the Texture so you can create separate TextureRegions that are flipped. A TextureRegion has low memory footprint.